# BeautifulSoup: Unable to get the next element

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get just the eBay title without the text "Details about". I tried using "next_sibling" but that doesn't work.

```
 title_BeautifulSoup = bs.find('h1', {'id': 'itemTitle'}).next_sibling
 # What I get in return: <div id="vi-itt-filler"></div>
```

[image]

Entire Code: https://pastebin.com/4NFLGDpp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use find_next('span') and `.next_element.next_element`

```
title_BeautifulSoup = bs.find('h1', {'id': 'itemTitle'}).find_next('span').next_element.next_element
print(title_BeautifulSoup)
```

OR contents and take the index 1

```
title_BeautifulSoup = bs.find('h1', {'id': 'itemTitle'}).contents
print(title_BeautifulSoup[1])
```

**Output:**

```
Invicta Men's Watch Pro Diver Quartz Black Dial Dive Quartz Bracelet 8932OB
```

Comment: I did not think about using contents like that. Nice.

Answer (score 0):

You could use stripped_strings and take index -1

```
title_BeautifulSoup = [s for s in bs.select_one('#itemTitle').stripped_strings][-1]
```

Or move on from the child span

```
title_BeautifulSoup = bs.select_one('#itemTitle .g-hdn').next_sibling
```